# Domain showing without WWW

Tags: dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirecting www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909600/redirecting-www-subdomain-example-com-to-subdomain-example-com)

I have a hard time understanding DNS mapping and such.

Right now, whether I type in my URL with or without WWW, it loads the site, but the URL displays without the WWW. But I would like the WWW to be displayed.

Domain registrar is Hover and Host is Laughing Squid

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any details around the server configuration, etc., but you apparently have DNS entries registered for both - pointing to the same site, but have a rewrite rule in effect that is redirecting the "www" version to the non-"www" version.

Comment: Thing is, I don't see any DNS entries! only mail CNAME

Comment: @jonasll - I assume you meant mail (MX) and CNAME?  CNAME is a DNS entry.  It works like an alias, and must be pointing to a host (A) record.  If you provide the URL, we could provide some specifics.

Comment: No, there is a CNAME for mail.url.com.

Comment: @Downvoter, please leave a comment as to your concern here?