# Redirect www subdomain under unknown other subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Basically my question is exactly this: [redirecting www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909600/redirecting-www-subdomain-example-com-to-subdomain-example-com)

We give all of our users a `myusername.ourdomain.com` link, the issue is when someone attempts to visit `www.myusername.ourdomain.com` our wildcard ssl gets broken and often the server will throw an error.

So the answer in the link I provided shows how to redirect a single `www.apachedefined.mydomain.com` I'm wondering how to use the same logic to do `www.thiscanbeanything.mydomain.com`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the very top of the htaccess file in your document root for the `www.*.mydomain.com` vhosts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm getting the error of:

You attempted to reach www.50.mydomain.net, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.mydomain.net. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.50.mydomain.net --- this is the same error we've always been receiving.

Comment: @Peter  are you redirecting or proxying?

Comment: It's through a Load Balancer so I'm wondering if that's causing it but now I get an SSL error on initial visit but afterwards all other visits do the redirect. That's odd. I edited my apache config directly instead of the htaccess as htaccess wasn't seeming to change anything.

Comment: EDIT: Yes the Load balancer is trying to do www.*.mydomain.net before the htaccess rules fire.. but the answer is working. Will mark as complete.