# Redirect www.sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I realize this has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909600/redirecting-www-subdomain-example-com-to-subdomain-example-com).
But I didn't really get the information I needed from the answers there.

I have a subdomain on **sub.domain.com**, now I have some people trying to access it using **www.sub.domain.com**, which is obviously a problem. I need to redirect people trying to use **www.** to **sub.domain.com**

I don't have much knowledge with .htaccess or A(Host)/CName but if someone can tell me exactly what records I need to add and what it needs to point to that would help alot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add DNS records (either CNAME or A) for `www.sub` under the `domain.com` domain, to point to the same place as `sub`. This will make it so when someone goes to `www.sub.domain.com`, they go to the same IP address as `sub.domain.com`.

Second, you need to add this rule to the htaccess file in your webserver's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, seems to work. Thanks a lot!