# .htaccess - Rewrite https://www.sub.domain.com to https://sub.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a .htaccess issue, and I don't know why, because it should be working.

What I'm trying to do with this code is redirect `https://www.sub.domain.com` to `https://sub.domain.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I test this code at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, it works succesfully.

(Request url: `https://www.sub.domain.com`, output url: `https://sub.domain.com`)

Also as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000821/redirect-www-sub-domain-com-to-sub-domain-com), I checked my DNS records , and there is an `www.sub` which points to the some domain as `sub` (both A's).

At this point I'm stuck, does anyone know what I did wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is fine. Make sure `VirtualHost` block for ssl is correct (document root and htaccess enabled)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know for sure htaccess is enabled. When I try something else like: `RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R,L]` in my public_html, to send every request over ssl, it works correctly.

Comment: Could you update your question with VirtualHost blocks (port 80 and 443) ?

Comment: Where can I find these? Sorry, but I'm a total noob at htaccess

Comment: In your apache configuration file

Comment: And where can I find this configuration file? I've searched for 5 minutes but can't find it..

Comment: It depends, but most of the time it can be found at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (you can see this question to see how to find it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202021/where-is-my-httpd-conf-file-located-apache )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68167/discussion-between-jifus-and-justin-iurman).

Answer (score -2):

Create a file called .htaccess in the doc root (web / httpdocs / www folder) of https://www.sub.domain.com and put in the code below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Err, that was a mistake. Updated!

Comment: OP's code didn't work while it was fine. How yours would help him without seeing much more about virtualhost config ?